# How to solve 'Mismatch of entities in the documents: rating, rating_store' error in Data migration Magento2.2.0?

Tags: magento2.2, migration

In data migration process, recently I faced this error in Rating Step:

> [ERROR]: Mismatch of entities in the documents: rating, rating_store

I check this both table and put ignore field value in map.xml.dist file.

But still, this error occurred in every migration process.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 4):

The **Ratings Step** does not transfer any data but assign 'is_active' = 1 for records in 'rating' table which are related in 'rating_store' table.

**So you can skip this step from execution and do it manually in your Magento 2 DB after migration.**

Comment following code:

> vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/source-to-destination/1.x.x.x/config.xml

```
<step title="Ratings Step">
    <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
    <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
    <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
</step>
```